# Flask submit form and show inserted values

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am completely new to python and Flask and I am trying to run in my computer the code showed in this page: 
http://runnable.com/UhLMQLffO1YSAADK/handle-a-post-request-in-flask-for-python

This are the steeps I follow and the code:

1-I have installed Flask

2-Files

**File app.py**

```
# We need to import request to access the details of the POST request
# and render_template, to render our templates (form and response)
# we'll use url_for to get some URLs for the app on the templates
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form_submit.html')

# Define a route for the action of the form, for example '/hello/'
# We are also defining which type of requests this route is 
# accepting: POST requests in this case
@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    name=request.form['yourname']
    email=request.form['youremail']
    return render_template('form_action.html', name=name, email=email)

# Run the app :)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run( 
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=int("80")
  )
```

**File form_action.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Handle POST requests with Flask</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>POST request with Flask</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                Hello <strong>{{name}}</strong> ({{email}})!
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**File form_submit.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Handle POST requests with Flask</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>POST request with Flask</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('hello') }}">
                  <label for="yourname">Please enter your name:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
                  <label for="youremail">Please enter your email:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="youremail" /><br />
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

3-I run the py file:

```
sudo python app.py
[sudo] password for jose: 
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I open the browser I write: 
file:///home/jose/Escritorio/python/app/form_submit.html

I insert the data in the 2 forms and I press Send and this is what happens:

URL: file:///home/jose/Escritorio/python/app/{{url_for('hello')}}

Web Page: File not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On your browser go to http://0.0.0.0:80/ , not file:///home/jose/Escritorio/python/app/form_submit.html

Comment: Thank you for answering, but now I have a problem. When I write 0.0.0.0:80, I get the following message: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: I edited my comment expalining the problem

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to, you shouldn't run Flask development server on port 80. It's not built for production. If you change that line to `app.run()` and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000 in your browser it should work

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 means that you can access the flask website from outside of the website host. Use the host ip plus the port # you specified
http://:80/hello in your case. That should display the form_action.html you specified in your routes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want save form data, your code didn't work. You must have a database or save in a file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i don't have  reputaion for comment

Comment: So in this case you should expand you answer, so it's not one sentence long.